# How to save the current safari tab using ScriptingBridge

Tags: objective-c, safari, scripting-bridge

I am trying to use the scripting-bridge to tell Safari to save the current page as PDF

In the "Safari.h" header file exists a saving method of SafariItem class:

```
- (void) saveAs:(NSString *)as in:(NSURL *)in_;
```

So I used this but it doesn't work:

```
[safariCurrentTab saveAs:@".PDF" in:filePath];
```

Later I noticed that saving as PDF is in the print option in Safari.app, so I tried to use this function

```
- (void) print:(NSURL *)x printDialog:(BOOL)printDialog withProperties:(SafariPrintSettings *)withProperties;
```

However when I tried to init a SafariPrintSettings object, it caused compile error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SafariPrintSettings", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Seems that the compiler doesn't find that class, but I did include the header file and add the ScriptingBridge framework

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So neither `saveAs:` nor `SafariPrintSettings` will work.

The "Save As..." functionality in the Safari app only provides HTML, and Scripting Bridge will only provide you with those options.  That's the thing to keep in mind: Scripting Bridge is a way to automate things you would do in the interface.

Except for "printing to PDF".  There is no printer object for producing PDFs.  OS X calls upon one (or many, it's hard to say) utilities to convert the HTML to PDF.

## Possible solution using `NSTask`

In `/System/Libary/Printers/Libraries/` you'll find `convert` (which is not to be confused with the system-wide ImageMagick convert... they're not the same!).  If you wanted to go this route, *you'd have to save the page as an HTML file first*, then you could use `NSTask` to run the `convert` command, like so:

```
NSTask *convert = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[convert setLaunchPath:@"/System/Libary/Printers/Libraries/convert"];
[convert setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-f",@"fileYouSaved.html",@"-o","foo.pdf",nil]];
//set output and so on...
[convert launch];
//this runs the command as if it were "convert -f fileYouSaved.html -o foo.pdf"
```

But it seems flaky; some elements were left hanging off the "printable" page on some of the wider websites I tried.

## Easiest possible solution

There is a third-party command line app/Ruby gem that might remove a lot of work called `wkpdf`.  You would simply execute:

`wkpdf --source http://www.apple.com --output apple.pdf`

and it would grab the page online and do what you need.  Alternatively, once you've installed it on your system, you can also call it in your app using `NSTask`, if you have more steps you need to take with the PDF file.

You can find `wkpdf` here: http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/